# I am getting a error message on the last line of my code

Tags: python-3.x

When I check my code for any errors I am getting w292- no new line. It is giving me this error on the very last line of code.

```
 def play_end():
    print_pause("Sorry but you have exhausted your spins.")
    print_pause("Thank You for playing spin the wheel")
    exit)
intro()
play_game(count)
play_end()
```

Comment: exit), ) should be removed

Comment: or the opening  bracket is missing